# Bootstrap model showing the same text each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap modal for showing a popup:

```
<% @yourphotos.each do |photo| %>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><%= name %></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
          <% if photo.caption != nil %>
          <%= photo.caption.text %>
        <% else %>
          nil text
        <% end %>           
          </p>
        </div>
          <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
          <input type="text" class="span2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Comment</button>
        </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Lets say I loop through the above and have 10 photos (in @yourphotos) my caption.text in each of the modals when I launch is the same each time even though when I view source I can see the 10 different modal captions..is this a JavaScript thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you open the modal? Maybe you keep on opening the same modal all the time?

Comment: Yes - this was correct. I was launching the same modal each time, silly oversight. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try one of Following (For bootstrap 3). It will remove the loaded data before open next time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
    });
});
```

Or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
```

Or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
```

[Reference Link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)